# How to apply function to each of the vectors in the vertical (3rd) direction of an array in R?

Tags: r

I'm new to the R language and is now stuck with a simple question.

Say I've got an array: `A <- array(1:12, c(2, 2, 3))`. I would like to use "apply" to calculate the mean of the elements in each of the 4 vectors in the vertical (3rd) dimension. (i.e. the result would be a 2 by 2 matrix)

The answer in this case should be:

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8
```

I've only come up with the idea of using 2 for loops to calculate the mean for 4 times. However since my array is very big, I was wondering is there a simple way to use "apply" to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
> apply(A, c(1,2), mean)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8
```

#### Edit

If you want to get the means of each column in each of the 3 matrices, then try:

```
> apply(A, 2:3, mean)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.5  5.5  9.5
[2,]  3.5  7.5 11.5
```

Note that the index in `apply` are 1 is for rows (the first dimension of an array), 2 is for columns (the second dimension of an array) and 3 is for the third dimension of your array

Comment: Thank you! I think I got what you mean. But what if I want to get the means of each column in each of the 3 matrices? (should return 6 values) I've tried apply(A,2,mean) but it's not correct.